vcpkg doesn't install .so or .a files for libmagic C library
I am attempting to use libmagic in a rust project, using the magic rust crate which provides rust bindings for the libmagic C library. Instructions for Windows say to install libmagic using vcpkg, which is seemingly supposed to bring with it the .so or .a files that the rust binding expects to find. However, my installation seems to have only .c and .h files, causing linker errors when I try to compile. It does contain magic.lib, but the linker can't seem to find that either, even when I properly set the MAGIC_DIR and VCPKG_ROOT environment variables.
Why does my installation not have these compiled libraries? Do I need to compile them myself? If so, how? What do I need to do to get the rust binding working?
Edit: It seems .so and .a are for linux, and .lib are what I should expect to see on Windows. The linker error I get says note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'magic.lib'. I've looked and made sure that magic.lib is in the correct place in the vcpkg installation of libmagic.

From what I'm seeing from the requirements here, it only suggests vcpkg on Windows in which case you'd get a .dll and/or .lib instead of .so and/or .a. So are you on Windows?

Yes, on windows. I didn't realize .so and .a didn't apply to windows. The documentation doesn't seem to have been written with Windows in mind, all I saw was talking about pointing the rust binding towards .so and .a files. It still wouldn't see the .lib file, which could confirm from looking at the files did exist. I'll edit the question to include the error message I got.
